# How to update libeigen3 to version >= 3.3 on 16.04 xenial?

Tags: 16.04, libraries

### Issue:

I have libeigen3 from the official repo installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev 
[sudo] password for nicolas: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libeigen3-dev is already the newest version (3.3~beta1-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

it says it's a 3.3 version, as this command does:

```
$ dpkg -s libeigen3-dev | grep 'Version'
Version: 3.3~beta1-2
```

However, version in file `/usr/lib/cmake/eigen3/Eigen3Config.cmake` is set to:

```
set ( EIGEN3_VERSION_STRING "3.2.92" )
```

### Question:

I wonder why? 
And how could I fix that because I need at least Eigen3.3 for to build an other software.

Comment: if there isn't problem to say it, can you precise which software you want to build?

Comment: it's FOSS so there is no problem: https://github.com/alicevision/AliceVision.git

Comment: Often the beta versions are named this way in a lot of software: Add a high minor version like "92" that shows that 3.2.92 is near to 3.3.0

Answer (score 1):

1. Try "apt-pinning" of the package libeigen3-dev from another newer Ubuntu version or
2. do it manually by downloading the deb-file from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libeigen3-dev (by clicking on "all" that directs to https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/libeigen3-dev/download) and then install it by `sudo dpkg -i libeigen3-dev_3.3.4-4_all.deb` (or whatever version you have downloaded). It should work flawless since there are not difficult dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

You can download eigen directly from its main website:

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Finally, follow the instruction in the `INSTALL` file:

```
$ cat INSTALL Installation instructions for Eigen
***********************************

Explanation before starting
***************************

Eigen consists only of header files, hence there is nothing to compile
before you can use it. Moreover, these header files do not depend on your
platform, they are the same for everybody.

Method 1. Installing without using CMake
****************************************

You can use right away the headers in the Eigen/ subdirectory. In order
to install, just copy this Eigen/ subdirectory to your favorite location.
If you also want the unsupported features, copy the unsupported/
subdirectory too.

Method 2. Installing using CMake
********************************

Let's call this directory 'source_dir' (where this INSTALL file is).
Before starting, create another directory which we will call 'build_dir'.

Do:

  cd build_dir
  cmake source_dir
  make install

The "make install" step may require administrator privileges.

You can adjust the installation destination (the "prefix")
by passing the -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=myprefix option to cmake, as is
explained in the message that cmake prints at the end.
```

Do not forget to link to these new libraries in cmake for any program using it if they are installed in parallel from the official ones! ;)